# How to use oracle keyword "desc" as a field name in Spring boot entity class

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa

The table was not being created for the following model despite following the correct procedure
**Model**

```
  @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @Entity
    public class Product {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        Integer pid;
    
        String name;
        String desc;
        double price;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `desc` is a reserved word and cannot be used, or you need to explicitly escape the name with an `@Column` annotation, something like `@Column(name='\`desc\`')`.

Comment: yes, I got that after a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was creating an entity class for JPA where there was a field name desc. I was using MySQL database. But for some reason, I was getting the following error.
**The model**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer pid;

    String name;
    String desc;
    double price;
}
```

[image]

Later I changed the field name and the whole thing was working. The ORM was automatically creating the table.
**The updated model that works**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer pid;

    String name;
    String description;
    double price;
}
```